# Does a downloaded page still send statistics of usage to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I was wondering whether a downloaded page still sends statistics to Google Analytics. I mean, even if it's been accessed in  the browser in the URL address like: file://downloadedwebpage.html

Would the account of the typical GA UI Tracking code still would know about this? The one we use like this:

`ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics in the default configuration tests the protocol and tries to set a cookie (via the [checkProtocolTask and the checkStorageTask](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks) respectively. The new gtag.js still uses the analytics.js library, so I expect it will work in the same way).

It does not consider "file://" to be a valid protocol, and cannot set a cookie on a page without a qualified domain. This behaviour can be overridden, but at standard GA tag would not track a page that is run via "file://".